# Incapacitate an enforced guard

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

How can I incapacitate (take down but not kill him) an enforced guard with gas-mask in Splinter Cell, beyond the case that you can drop from the sky :D

Thanks and kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh forget it, I found the answer. I'll post it if someone needs it, is very easy, just come from behind like this video (second 332)